# Kubernetes Max number of pods with NodePort

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploying multiple pods, each one has to be exposed.
I learned that I can expose those using a service with type NodePort.

The problem I am facing here is that a port is assigned per pod, cluster-wide. This limits the number of pods I can expose to +/- 65000 (number of linux ports).

I wonder if there was a possibility to expose a pod with a port only on the worker node where it is running on, e.g. 10.10.0.30:30001. In this way, the port 30001 would be available on other worker nodes for other pods.
I understand that if the pod was to die and re-scheduled elsewhere it would have to be allocated a free port again.

Is this even possible?
Are there otherwise an alternative how to expose a large number of pods (200000+)

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the following documents: [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/), [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), [Configuration Best Practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have done that before posting. I am afraid it didn't answer my question.

Anyway, I am currently looking into leveraging Traefik ingress controller so that I don't need to use service NodePort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a limit on the supported configurations, both for the number of pods to 100 per node, and 150,000 pods per cluster - [see docs about building large clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/cluster-large/).

What you're trying to achieve isn't possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use externalIP in service yaml, like below, here x.x.x.x can be IP of any kubernetes nodes and 8080 will be expose in that node.
spec:
   ports:
   - name: http
     port: 80
     targetPort: 8080
   selector:
      app: nginx
   type: LoadBalancer
   externalIPs:
   - x.x.x.x